# Find a specific text in tr td jquery using contains

Tags: javascript, jquery, uitableview, html-table

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/g5Vqn/1304/) is my fiddle of finding a text in tr.

I used

```
var reports = $('table#reports > tbody');
var tr1 = reports.find('tr:has(td:contains("First Name"))');
```

to find the text but even if the text does not exist it still alerts that it exists. To check if it exist i created an `if`

```
if (tr1) {
    alert('exist');
 } else {
    alert('not');
 }
```

Comment: jQuery objects are always truthy, test the `.length` property of `tr1` I.E. `if(tr1.length){...`

Comment: `contains` check for `substring`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bayo0d0r/1/ - the jQuery object will always be truthy so check its length to see whether there is a element inside it

Comment: i thought it is false by default lol.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @ArunPJohny you can post the answer

Comment: @A.Wolff because it looked like there is a duplicate....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find)(infact all [traversing methods](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)) return a jQuery object which is always truthy, so your condition will always be true.

If you want to see whether the selector found any matches then you can check the length property of the jQuery object which will give the number of dom element references returned by the selector, so if there are no matched elements it will return 0

so

```
if (tr1.length) {
    alert('exist');
} else {
    alert('not');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if tr1 is not undefined and length is greater than 1